# Gatsby / Netlify Styles wont show?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

When I'm using the Gatsby starter `https://www.gatsbyjs.org/starters/gatsby-starter-business` Locally I see all the styles fine and everything works. When i deploy to *Netlify* I don't get any css to show up! I can't seem to figure out why?

Here is the *Netlify* link `https://nostalgic-boyd-5136cc.netlify.com/` and repo `https://github.com/mikeytown19/cftc` Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

There is a conflict with a module in your project (`package.json`) using the version 1.x of Gatsby using `"gatsby-plugin-sass": "^1.0.26"` and having `node-sass`.

### Solution:

```
yarn remove node-sass
```

`node-sass` is a peer dependency in the version 2.x of `gatsby-plugin-sass` plugin. This is not the case in version 1.x

Comment: The plugin has it in a footnote at the end of the `README.md` so it is not easy to see.